# Undefined subroutine in perl &library1::func1

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am calling a function (func1) from library2.pm in library1.pm. And the function is called simply as &func1(), since I declared " use library2 " in library1. But this is throwing an error as the undefined subroutine. But when I am calling that function as " &library2::func1 "  it is working. Am I missing any Perl package here?

Comment: Please provide the a minimal demonstration of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you export the function? It's hard to tell what you're missing since you didn't post any code! I could explain why you need what's missing if I knew what it was. Instead, you'll have to settle for an example of what's needed.

`library2.pm` should include:

```
package library2;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter qw( import );

our @EXPORT = qw( func1 );

...

sub func1 { ... }

...

1;
```

`library1.pm` should include:

```
package library1;

use strict;
use warnings;

use library2;

...

func1(...)

...

1;
```

---

By the way, the name of the language is Perl, not PERL. It's not an acronym.

---

By the way, you should stop using `&` in front of sub calls; there's no reason to tell Perl to ignore the prototypes of the subs you call.

---

By the way, lower-case module names are technically reserved for use by Perl. But more importantly, convention reserves lower-case modules for pragma modules (modules that affect the language, and modules that are lexically-scoped in effect). Please avoid lower-case module names.

---

By the way,

```
use library2 qw( func1 );
```

is generally better than

```
use library2;
```

because it's easier to see where subs are defined, and it prevents surprises if the default exports of a module ever change.

Comment: The mentioned syntax by you is absolutely correct. But When I'm calling func1 in library1 without specifying library2::func1, then I'm getting error. I want to know exact reason for it and Thanks for your response.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're missing since you didn't post any code! I could explain why you need what's missing if I knew what it was. Instead, you'll have to settle for an example of what's needed. If you were to provide a demonstration of your problem, we'll be able to provide more information. Or at the very least, you can tell me which lines that I posted that are missing from your code.

Comment: That's fine. Thank you very much